# Removing consequent prefix in perl string

Tags: regex, string, perl

I have a file I need to reformat which contains a string like this:

> pin_name[10], pin_name[9], pin_name[8], ..., other_pin_name, some_other_pin_name[1], some_other_pin_name[0]

What I want to obtain is a string like this:

> pin_name[10], [9], [8], ..., other_pin_name, some_other_pin_name[1], [0]

So, I want to remove all subsequent duplicate prefixes and leave only the suffix which is different. Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: Are the "pins" in order? In other words, will there be something like `pin[3],pin[2],another[0],pin[1]`?

Comment: The pins are ordered from high to low, always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -pe 's/\b((\w+)\[\d+\])((?:,\s*\2\[\d+\])+)/$a=$1;$b=$3;$b=~s,$2,,g;$a.$b/eg'
```

Comment: Thanks, that works on a file. As I need to use this in perl for some formatting, and I have it imported and split into an array, how would I do the same thing on the elements in the array?

Comment: Really, that's a separate question (or your original question should have made this clear).  But anyway: `my $x; for (@array) { $x = $1 if (!s/^${x}(\[\d+\])/\1/ && /^(\w+)\[\d+\]/) }`

Comment: slightly better version (as I can't edit the above comment anymore): `my $x; for (@array) { $x = (s/^(${x})(\[\d+\])/\2/ || /^(\w+)\[\d+\]/) ? $1 : '' }`